# Trigger mouseover event on a Raphael map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

I am using the Raphael plugin for the first time and so far I managed to create a map of Germany and to outline all different regions inside. I found out how to bind mouse-over effects, so when I hover over a region its color changes. Everything looks fine until the moment when I want to trigger the same mouse-over effect from outside the map. There is a list of links to all the regions and each link should color its respective geographical position (path) on the map when hovered. The problem is that I don't know how to trigger the mouse-over effect from outside.

This is the reference guide I used for my code: [Clickable France regions map](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/07/18/create-clickable-svg-france-regions-map.html)

This is my map initialization:

```
var regions = [];

var style = {
    fill: "#f2f2f2",
    stroke: "#aaaaaa",
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "stroke-linejoin": "round",
    cursor: "pointer",
    class: "svgclass"
};

var animationSpeed = 500;

var hoverStyle = {
    fill: "#dddddd"
}

var map = Raphael("svggroup", "100%", "auto");
map.setViewBox(0, 0, 585.5141, 792.66785, true);

// declaration of all regions (states)
....
var bayern = map.path("M266.49486,..,483.2201999999994Z");
bayern.attr(style).data({ 'href': '/bayern', 'id': 'bayern', 'name': 'Bayern' }).node.setAttribute('data-id', 'bayern');
regions.push(bayern);
```

This is where my "normal" mouse effects take place:

```
for (var regionName in regions) {
    (function (region) {
        region[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            if (region.data('href')) {
                region.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed);
            }
        }, true);

        region[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            if (region.data('href')) {
                region.animate(style, animationSpeed);
            }
        }, true);

        region[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var url = region.data('href');

            if (url){
                location.href = url;
            }
        }, true);
    })(regions[regionName]);
}
```

I have a menu with links and I want to bind each of them to the respective region, so that I can apply the animations, too.

```
$("ul.menu__navigation li a").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    // this function displays my pop-ups
    showLandName($(this).data("id"));
    // $(this).data("id") returns the correct ID of the region
});
```

I would appreciate any ideas! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. It surely isn't the most optimal one, especially in terms of performance, but at least it gave me the desired output. I would still value a better answer, but as of right now a new loop inside the mouse-over event does the job.

```
$("ul.menu__navigation li a").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    // this function displays my pop-ups
    showLandName($(this).data("id"));

    // animate only the one hovered on the link list
    var test = '/' + $(this).data("id");

    for (var regionName in regions) {
        (function (region) {
            if (region.data('href') === test) {
                region.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed);
            }        
        })(regions[regionName]);
    }
});
```